# c#, html-agility-pack get text which is not inside tags

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

This is my HTML:

```
<a class="bla"></a>
25 oct 2012
```

How can I get only 25 oct 2012. The text is not inside any tags.
I am using the c# htmlagilitypack library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can use `text()` to reference text nodes in XPath. Try to pass the following XPath to HtmlAgilityPack's `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()` method :

```
//a[@class='bla']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

brief explanation :

- `//a[@class='bla']` : find `<a>` element, anywhere in the HTML document, that have `class` attribute equals `"bla"`...
- `/following-sibling::text()[1]` : then from such `<a>` return the nearest text node that follows